# Gerrit rejected push for valid LDAP member

Tags: gerrit

In Gerrit setup for one repository, access has been inherited from "All-Projects" & on top of it, added reference "refs/head/*" with permission "Push" for "ldap/git_developers" internal LDAP group. And account "abcde" is part of this LDAP group.

However, Push is being restricted currently.
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (prohibited by Gerrit)

But if I add "Registered Users" for the same reference & permission "Push", it works fine for account "abcde". Are there any other settings missing to make it work along with LDAP group only?

Thanks....

Comment: Can anybody help here? Since LDAP group is not being picked up correctly, we are currently mapping those members to Gerrit internal group manually.

Comment: Kindly someone look into this & help! - Anugrith V

Comment: I believe this might help http://stackoverflow.com/q/33585208/1387060