# Using LDAP account while pushing to Gerrit

Tags: gerrit

I have successfully installed Gerrit and configured it to use LDAP. Now users can login to the GUI with their accounts however they can't push new code. After googling the problem I figured that they must define an HTTP password or SSH hey in order to be used while pushing new code.

Is there any way to use the LDAP password instead of creating a separate HTTP password?

Comment: I think [auth.gitBasicAuth](https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.11.4/config-gerrit.html#auth.gitBasicAuth) should help.

Comment: This is correct. I added the configuration and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33585208/using-ldap-account-while-pushing-to-gerrit#comment54947084_33585208),
Adding gitBasicAuth = true within [auth] fixed the problem. This configuration could be found in gerrit_installation_path/etc/gerrit.config